# useEffect hook can't set the state of product first time using the setProduct() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getParticularProduct } from "../services/productService";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function ParicularProduct() {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
        getParticularProduct(id).then((response) => {
          setProduct(response.data.product);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
    }
  }, []);

  console.log(product);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex w-full border border-solid">
        <div className="flex flex-row border border-solid w-full mt-20 p-5">
          <img className='w-1/3' src={"http://" + product.images.host} />
          {/* <div className="w-2/3">{product.name}</div> */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default ParicularProduct;
```

I also tried useEffecct hook with an blank dependency array. It is render only 1 time. But it returns my default state only which is "{}". if I change something in my code it re-rendered and showing the result i want and if i refresh the page it returns the default state"{}"

Please help. Thank You...

Comment: You have to add the second argument (dependency array) to `useEffect`. Now it runs on every update.

Comment: Replace `product.images.host` with `product.images?.host`

Comment: is your `setProduct` is even running? probably the `getParticularProduct` method is failing, therefore your `then` block is never executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a very good example of some common pitfalls using hooks. Firstly, `useEffect` without dependency array will run every time any state or prop changes. That is the same as not using `useEffect` hook at all. So, please always add dependency array to your `useEffect`.

In this case, you want `useEffect` to run only once when the component is mounted. So, pass in an empty array.

```
useEffect(()=>{
//....
}, []);
```

I believe this should solve the issue. However, please do this one change. If it does not work, update your question to include the new error message.

Happy coding!

### Update

I believe your code is throwing error before console.log is called second time - after product update. Change following line

```
<img className='w-1/3' src={"http://" + product.images.host} />
```

to

```
<img className='w-1/3' src={"http://" + product.images?.host} />
```

Comment: Sorry Sir. I am really new to react. I tried your thing but it only returns me the my default state "{}" which is a blank object. I also updated the Question. Thank You sir.

Comment: Oh my god! It works very fine. Thank You sir. Thank You so much.

Comment: I am sorry sir i am annoying you but Can you please tell me what does the question marks means there?

Comment: It's a null/undefined check - prevents throwing error when `images` is undefined

Comment: Welcome! On Stack Overflow, we say thanks by upvoting and accepting the answer so that others also may get benefitted.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    try {
        getParticularProduct(id).then((response) => {
            setProduct(response.data.product);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.response.data);
    }
}, []);
```

To see the updated state, you can use another useEffect hook with a dependency on the product variable. This effect will run whenever product changes and log the updated value:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(product);
}, [product]);
```

Comment: Sorry sir... This is not working... Same problem...